# Trouble adding Volley to Android project

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-volley

I've tried to add Volley as a dependency to my Java module inside my Android Studio project, but I have not been able to get it to work.

I've put this inside both my `build.gradle` files dependencies lists (for my Android module and my Java module):

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.2.0'
```

But if I try to use the library in a class, I get this [message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP5px.png) and clicking it doesn't do anything.
I've also tried to manually import the library:

```
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
```

But I get a "Cannot resolve symbol 'Volley'" error here as well.

If I try to use the library in my android module (the one that handles the activities etc.) it works without any problems. But when trying to use it in the Java module that I created, it doesn't.

Comment: Because Volley is an Android library, not a "pure Java library". Maybe use Retrofit?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce this was the problem. Retrofit did work as a solution, but I decided to restructure my project and still use Volley inside an Android class, which worked. Mind posting an answer so I can mark it as solved?

Answer (score 0):

Hello can you post the build.gradle module and app files  ?

1. try removing the Volley dependency , sync the gradle file then add it again and sync
2. delete the .gradle file from your project then sync it again

Android should be able to detect Classes from libraries and import them automatically if the library is imported correctly , so your problem most likely is that the library isnt imported at all

Comment: As someone has commented, Volley is not a "pure Java library" so using it in a pure Java class did not work. I've decided to restructure my project and use Volley inside an Android class and that works.